# How to auto adding a blank line before class close on code format

Tags: phpstorm

I able to configure the make PHPStorm IDE to add a blank line after class open. But I could not find a config option to add blank line before class close.

Thanks

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the maximum balnk lines to 2 like this:

[image]